# Find cosine distance for all pairs of word2vec encodings without using nested loops

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, word2vec

I need to calculate and store **cosine distances for all pairs of words of a word2vec encoding**. Each word is represented as a 4 * 1 vector stored in a pandas dataframe, with each element in the contunuous range [1, 9].
I need to store the result in a pandas dataframe so that it can be accessed in constant time. 

I am unable to use the apply function of pandas library/lambda. Using nested loops will take approx. 9 hours (according to tqdm).

```
word     word1    word2    word3 ...
word1    d11      d12      d13...
word2    d21      d22      d23...
word3    d31      d32      d33...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why can you not use lambda functions? Also, nested for loops really aren't efficient. You might be better of using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) explicitly. For performance, you might also consider [cythonizing](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) your code.

Comment: I tried both, taking a lot of time, which is the most efficient method?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, from the pandas docs: [Enhancing Performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use something like the Python `gensim` library to load a pre-existing vector set (in the original word2vec.c format) into its `KeyedVectors` representation, then the raw vectors will be in a numpy array in its `vectors` property. For example:

```
kv = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('word_vectors.bin', binary=True)
print(kv.vectors.shape)
```

You could then use a library function like `scikit-learn`'s [`pairwise_distances()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) to compute the distance matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
distances = pairwise_distances(kv.vectors, metric="cosine")
```

Because the `sklearn` routine uses optimized native math routines, it will likely be a lot faster than your initial loops-in-pure-Python approach. Note, though, that the resulting distances matrix may be huge!

(You can find out which words are in which `kv.vectors` slots via the list in `kv.index2entity`, or look up the slot for a word via the dict in `kv.vocab`.)